# Efficiency list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, file, data-structures

Hello I'm moving from VB to python and I'm doing some of my first projects to learn the syntax and the basics of the language, what I'm trying to do now is a sort of simulation of a "management app" before working with databases I'm doing it first with files.

What I do is having this file (which will be my database in the future) where I have stored the informations about some employees the data I store are
I'd ,name ,surname ,date of birth ,status, code , contract
On the file I have them stored like this
1|Bob|Brown|07/12/1985|Active|202020|1
(The pin is a number I generate to let the user "login" to see his informations and the contract is an id of the contracts that I have on another file so the foreign key)

Now I store all of these in a list of dictionaries so my overall data structure would look like this

```
[{Id:1,name:Bob, surname:Brown, dateB:07/12/1985,status:Active,code:202020, contact:1},{Id:2,name:Josh, surname:Allen, dateB:05/02/1999,status:Active,code:202021, contact:3}]
```

Each time I add a new employee I create a new dictionary like

```
NewEmpl = dict(id=3,name=Robert,surname=Lasky,dateB=03/11/1997,status=Active, code=202022, contract=2)
list_employees.append(NewEmpl)
F.write(str(id)+"|"+name+"|"+surname.....
```

update both the file and the list but I wonder if there is a more efficient way to store the data than how I'm doing right know with a list of dictionaries

Comment: instead of a list of dicts you could have a dict of dicts, which will improve speed when calling a specific row... `dict_employees = {1: employee1_dict, 2: employee2_dict}`, or use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/). It is designed to be used for tabular data. Since it's written using [numpy](https://numpy.org/) which uses c++ it is very efficient. You can turn your list of dicts to a DataFrame as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list_employees)
```

And to a csv it is as simple as:

```
df.to_csv('file.csv')
```